# Request changes/additions to data in another app

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

To make a long story short, I am very grateful for hints on how I can accomplish the following. I have an app A that I don't want to change. I have an app B that needs to select data from A or to request data to be added/changed if necessary. Think of B as an app to suggest data that should end in A only after review/approval. By itself, B is pretty useless. Furthermore, a significant amount of what B's users will enter needs to be rejected. That's why I want A to be protected so to say.

```
# in app A
class Some_A_Model(models.Model): #e.g., think artist
    some_value = models.TextField()

# in app B
class MyCustomField(models.ForeignKey):
    ...

class Some_B_Model(models.Model): # e.g., think personal preference
    best_A = MyCustomField('Some_A_Model')
    worst_A = MyCustomField('Some_A_Model')
    how_many_times_I_like_the one_better_than_the_other = models.FloatField()

class Mediator(models.Model):
    # already exists: generic foreign key
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(
        ContentType,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey(
        'content_type',
        'object_id'
    )
    #does not yet exist or needs to be changed: 
    add_or_change = PickledObjectField()
```

Django should create a form for Some_B_Model where I can select instances of Some_A_Model for best_A and worst_A, respectively; if, however, my intended best_A is not yet in A's database, I want to be able to request this item to be added. And if I find worst_A is present but has a typo, I want to be able to request this item to be corrected. An editor should be required to review/edit the data entered in B and either reject or release all the associated changes to A's database as an atomic transaction. I don't want any garbage in A and refrain from adding some status field to track what is considered valid, requiring filtering all the time. If it's in A, it must be good.

I figured I need to define a MyCustomField, which could be a customized ForeignKey. In addition, I need some intermediate model ('mediator' maybe?) that MyCustomField would actually be pointing to and that can hold a (generic) ForeignKey to the item I selected, and a pickled instance of the item I would like to see added to A's database (e.g., a pickled, unsaved instance of Some_A_model), or both to request a change. Note that I consider using PickledObjectField from 'django-picklefield', but this is not a must.

As there is only some documentation on custom model fields but not on the further steps regarding form fields and widgets, it seems I have to dig through django's source to find out how to tie my intended functionality into its magic. That's where I am hoping for some comments and hints. Does my plan sound reasonable to you? Is this a known pattern, and if so, what is it called? Maybe someone has already done this or there is a plugin I could look into? What alternatives would you consider?

Many thanks in advance!

Best regards

Comment: I don't understand why it needs to be so complicated. Can't you replicate the data as a B model first (meaning a copy of the A_Model in the B app, or of the relevant fields of A_Model as draft) and once it's approved copy it to A?

Comment: Note that there is documentation about [how to specify the form field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-model-fields/#specifying-the-form-field-for-a-model-field) and [custom widgets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/widgets/#base-widget-classes).

Comment: @dirkgroten Many thanks for your reply. Most of the times I expect the Mediator to just be a pointer to an existing Some_A_model, so the ability to just select those items in B's forms is essential. Copying fields over to some 'mirror model' would allow for holding the infomation outside of A, true, but would be blank and also introduce new pk's, so I don't quite get how this could help me. Regarding documentation you are right, I put this wrong, it's rather that the tutorial-style documentation leaves out the further parts [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-model-fields].